# How to get Yodlee FastLink URL with Java HTTP request code?

Tags: apache-httpclient-4.x, resttemplate, yodlee

I'm testing out Yodlee. I'm able to get FastLink working via POSTing a FORM element in my Chrome browser. I believe there is some type of redirect happening after the POST that tells Chrome to go to another URL address and that page loads. I want to do the POST with Java code and capture the redirect URL.

I've tried with the below RestTemplate code but the request hangs and the connection is eventually killed.

```
MultiValueMap<String, String> map = new LinkedMultiValueMap<String, String>(); 
map.add("rsession", getUserAuthToken()); 
map.add("token", fastLinkAccess.getAccessToken()); 
map.add("app", "10003600"); 
map.add("redirectReq", "true");

URI uri = template.postForLocation("https://node.developer.yodlee.com/authenticate/restserver/", map, String.class);
```

How can I go about this?

Answer (score 0):

It will be possible to launch Fastlink by posting HTML content to the action(node) URL only.

As you are using java, you can use the following sample code to post a HTML using java-

```
String formHtmlContent = "<div class='center processText'>Processing...</div>" 
    + "<div>"
    + "<form action='${NODE_URL}' method='post' id='rsessionPost'>"
    + " RSession : <input type='text' name='rsession' placeholder='rsession' value='${RSESSION}' id='rsession'/><br/>"
    + " FinappId : <input type='text' name='app' placeholder='FinappId' value='${FINAPP_ID}' id='finappId'/><br/>"
    + " Redirect : <input type='text' name='redirectReq' placeholder='true/false' value='true'/><br/>"
    + " Token : <input type='text' name='token' placeholder='token' value='${TOKEN}' id='token'/><br/>" 
    + " Extra Params : <input type='text' name='extraParams' placeholder='Extra Params' value='${EXTRA_PARAMS}' id='extraParams'/><br/>"
    + "</form></div><script>document.getElementById('rsessionPost').submit();</script>";
```